# How to run two infinite loop at once in same program in c

Tags: c

So this is for my project where I want to print current date and time and run timer.
But when I run the program it only prints the date and time . If I don't run it for infinite times then it only prints the time When I ran that program. And i need to run two infinite loops in same program.
One for current date and time and another for timer.

sorry for posting this rough code because my code is incomplete.
I just want to know how to run two infinite loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
  
  char cur_time[128];
  for(;;)
  {
  time_t      t;
  struct tm*  ptm;
  
  t = time(NULL);
  ptm = localtime(&t);
    
  strftime(cur_time, 128, "%d-%b-%Y  %H:%M:%S", ptm);
  printf("\rCurrent date and time: %s", cur_time);
  }
  
  for(;;)
  {
    printf("I Can't print This Line !!");
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: use ONE infinite loop and differenatiate inside the loop which operation is to be performed. Else use a different process

Comment: An alternative is to use multi-threading (take a look at `pthread` or at C11 `<threads.h>`). It is not too difficult to setup multi-threading, but the hard part is to coordinate threads in case of shared resources.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and explain in more detail what your program is supposed to do and why you think that you need two independent infinite loops instead of one. In your example the most obvious solution wuld be to move the `printf` from the second loop to the first loop and remove the second one. But I guess your real program will do something different. What exactly do you mean with "*One for current date and time and another for timer.*"

Comment: I have two options for you:
1. You might use coroutines. But you have to read about them.
2. Use one infinite loop and put two infinite statements with `break;` conditionals inside them.

Comment: @Bodo One that shows system date and time
next one shows  timer ie. 00:00:01 
                                         00:00:02
                                         00:00:03
                                          and so on...

Comment: @R1S8K I got my answer but now I got stuck on another process .I can't display anything after the loop. Nothing gets executed.

Comment: OK, let me post an example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single threaded program can only be executing one instruction at a time. In your program, the second `while` loop will never be reached.

You have a few options: master event loop, multithreading, or separate processes.

---

A master event loop is the easiest method. Simply have a single infinite loop, in which all your logic is placed.

Note that everything in the loop happens in order, which means you'll want to avoid blocking the execution (waiting for user input, long computations, etc.) if you want the appearance of concurrency.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void display_time(void) {
    char cur_time[128];
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *ptm = localtime(&t);

    strftime(cur_time, 128, "%d-%b-%Y  %H:%M:%S", ptm);
    printf("Current date and time: %s\n", cur_time);
}

int main(void) {
    while (1) {
        display_time();
        puts("I can print this line.");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

---

Using [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) is another option. Multithreading shares the environment of the process between different threads of execution, so care must be taken when sharing resources.

Here's an example using POSIX threads (`-lpthread`).

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void display_time(void) {
    char cur_time[128];
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *ptm = localtime(&t);

    strftime(cur_time, 128, "%d-%b-%Y  %H:%M:%S", ptm);
    printf("Current date and time: %s\n", cur_time);
}

void *time_thread(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        display_time();
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thr;

    if (pthread_create(&thr, NULL, time_thread, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (1) {
        puts("I can print this line.");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

---

Using different processes is yet another option.

Here we duplicate our process' environment into a new process as soon as `fork` returns successfully (returning `0` in the child process, and the child's PID in the parent process), and execution resumes independently in both processes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void display_time(void) {
    char cur_time[128];
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *ptm = localtime(&t);

    strftime(cur_time, 128, "%d-%b-%Y  %H:%M:%S", ptm);
    printf("Current date and time: %s\n", cur_time);
}

void child_proc(void) {
    while (1) {
        display_time();
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create child process.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (pid == 0)
        child_proc();
    else while (1) {
        puts("I can print this line.");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much for your help
: )
Now I'm stuck in next process I can't display any thing after the loop .
Nothing gets executed.

Comment: @MrWhoseTheNoob A truly infinite loop *(one with no breakout condition)* will **never end**. As such, any code to be executed after the loop ends can never be reached. Remember that a single thread of execution can only do one thing at a time. For concurrency, consider threads or child processes. You should take your time to study these concepts. If you're really stuck after refactoring your code, then ask a separate question about these specific topics and how they relate to your new code.

Comment: Okay I'll study those concepts 
if I'm stuck I'll ask this question seperately.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to complicate things with threads, then just switch between the functions in a single loop:

```
void do_thing_1() { printf("..."); }

void do_thing_2() { printf("..."); }

void loop() {
    while (1) {
        do_thing_1();
        do_thing_2();
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to control the timing a bit better than that, but it will work. I do this often in embedded systems where the individual functions are state machines handling some piece of hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple scheme. It maybe near to what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void){

    int loop1_counter = 0;
    int loop2_counter = 0;

    while(1){
        printf("start of main loop\n");

        for(;;){
            printf("loop1 %d\n",loop1_counter);
            loop1_counter++;

            if(loop1_counter >= 5){
                loop1_counter = 0;
                break;
            }
        }


        printf("between loop1 and loop2\n");


        for(;;){
            printf("loop2 %d\n",loop2_counter);
            loop2_counter++;

            if(loop2_counter >= 5){
                loop2_counter = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("end of main loop\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```